# @NonNull triggers warning in Eclispse although constant value used

Tags: java, eclipse

I have got the following method definition:

```
public static @Nullable String getFile(@NonNull final Path path, @NonNull final Charset charset)
```

And invoking the method somewhere else with the following statement:

```
final String fileString = FileUtil.getFile(filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, now that I'm using the `import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull` annotation Eclipse triggers a warning:

[image: Eclipse Warning]

Why is this warning triggered although I'm using a constant (i.e. `StandardCharsets.UTF8`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration for `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` is:

```
public static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

As far as Eclipse null analysis is concerned it is possible that `Charset.forName` might return `null` so the `@NotNull` can't be guaranteed.

Comment: And how to deal with such a situation properly?

Comment: All you can do is suppress the warning.